# I dont want to clear the input of datepicker after submit

Tags: jquery, date, jsp, datepicker

data in input date picker disappear after submit.
but i still want it to stay even after submit
Please anyone help !

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
});
</script>
<input type="text" name="fromDate"
        id="datepicker1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**: You can save the value of the datepicker to the session by the following code:

```
var datepickerVal = $("#datepicker1").val();
 sessionStorage.setItem('datepicker', datepickerVal);
```

And then you can check on load if there is value datepickerVal in `sessionStorage`, then display in the input field by using the following code:

```
if(datepickerVal in sessionStorage && sessionStorage.getItem("datepicker")!=null){
  /*****Here set the value of input field to the required value****/
  $("input[id=datepickere1]").attr('value',sessionStorage.getItem("datepicker"));
}
```

Comment: are you using ajax call on form submissione?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-initialize your datepicker field after form submissione.
So you shoud need to write following code after form submission.

```
var oldValue = $('#dtFrom').val();
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy'
});
/* If want to preserve old selected value */
$('#dtFrom').val(oldValue);
```

In case of are using ajax call for form submission,

```
$.ajax({
    url :   'includes/action.php',
    method: "POST",
    data    : {recipe:1},
    dataType : "html",
    success : function(data){
         /* Initialize datepicker */
         var oldValue = $('#dtFrom').val();
         $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
                dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy'
         });
         /* If want to preserve old selected value */
         $('#dtFrom').val(oldValue);
    }
})
```